# Stop-IISSite without confirm dialog

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to use the powershell command Stop-IISSite but i don't want to have the confirmation dailog.

```
Stop-IISSite -Name "WebSiteName"
```

The "-Confirm" parameter doesn't work on my tests, is there any option to force this stop?

Comment: `-Force` perhaps ?

Comment: -Force is not known as parameter

Comment: How are you using `-Confirm`? `-Confirm:$false`?

Comment: I used the -Confirm parameter wrong, thx

Answer (score 5):

You can user

```
Stop-IISSite -Name "WebSiteName" -Confirm:$false
```

it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Run powershell as administrator.

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
```

[image]